# Good practice to make network calls in a fragment? Or should I pass data from the parent Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question. I'll be showing some charts inside a recycler view that is inside a viewpager fragment. Is it good practice to make network calls in the fragment or should I pass it from the activity? Here, the data will be 2-3 ArrayLists.

Comment: It does not matter. But you should keep in mind to do network operations on a non-ui thread.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be using Google's Volley Library to fetch data in the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A [retained fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) is an ideal host for a network call that conceptually belongs to the activity.  The fragment instance and its background task will survive configuration changes.  If you want the background task to survive other types of activity destruction, host it in a `Service`.